# How can I extract plain text (no markup) from QWebElement?

Tags: qt, qwebelement

I'm loading a URL into a QWebFrame in a new tab of a QTabWidget.  I then set the tab text to the  of the HTML document.  This works fine most of the time, but apparently QWebElement::toPlainText() returns the raw markup text.  So if the  has HTML comments inside it, I end up setting the Tab text to something like "My Title".  I expect it does the same with other markup, like &lt:, etc.

What is the best way of removing the comments?  I can't figure out how one is supposed to identify comment child elements of a QWebElement.

I guess that since the  element should only contain a simple string, I could resort to using regular expressions to remove the comments from the string returned by QWebElement::toPlainText().

Should I instead load the QWebElement title text into a QDomDocument and remove the comment elements from that?  Even that's starting to prove a little clunky.

---

Using QDomDocument didn't turn out so bad:

```
QDomDocument titleDoc;
titleDoc.setContent(QString("<x>%1</x>").arg(webFrame->title()));
m_tabWidget->setTabText(index, titleDoc.documentElement().text());
```

It just seemed like a big hammer.